# How to compute statistical significance on populations produced using an algorithm that involves repeated measures with unequal sample sizes

Tags: repeated-measures

I am new to this forum - please let me know if there is additional information required or suggested formatting tips. Cheers~

---

I have $n$ subjects. There is a discrete time course associated with each $j$th subject, where at a given $t_i$, there is a corresponding measured value $y_i$...i.e. $f_j(t_i)=y_i$. Throughout this time course, there are time intervals that periodically arise whose measured values I am interested in. For example, lets say I take $t_0, t_1, t_2$ as my first desired time window, and then take $t_{0+30k}$, $t_{1+30k}$, and $t_{2+30k}$ for any positive integer $k$ as my other desired time windows.

For each time window (let's use the first one for example), I determine the following average: $Y_0^j=\frac{f_j(t_0)+f_j(t_1)+f_j(t_2)}{3}$. For a given subject $j$'s time course, I create two categories: $S_{\text{pos}}^j$ and $S_{\text{neg}}^j$. If $Y_0^j \gt 0$, I assign $Y_0^j$ to $S_{\text{pos}}^j$. If $Y_0^j \lt 0$, I assign $Y_0^j$ to $S_{\text{neg}}^j$. I carry on this process for all $Y_k^j$'s within the $j$th subject.

I repeat this procedure for all $n$ subjects. At the conclusion of this procedure, each $j$th subject has its own $S_{\text{pos}}^j$ and $S_{\text{neg}}^j$ "post-hoc categories". I denote the **size** of each category as $|S|$, where "size" here refers to the number of assignments. For example, if *Subject 1*'s **neg** category is denoted as $ S_{\text{neg}}^1$, and $ S_{\text{neg}}^1=\{Y_1^1, Y_4^1, Y_{13}^1\}$, then $ |S_{\text{neg}}^1|=3$.

Importantly, it can certainly be the case that $|S_{\text{pos}}^1| \neq |S_{\text{pos}}^2|$, as well as $|S_{\text{neg}}^1| \neq |S_{\text{neg}}^2|$. Further, because certain $Y_k^j$'s may equal $0$, no assignment of that $Y_k$ will take place. Consequently, it can also be the case that  $|S_{\text{pos}}^1| + |S_{\text{neg}}^1| \neq |S_{\text{pos}}^2| + |S_{\text{neg}}^2|$.

Finally, there is a **different** discrete time course measured *simultaneously* during the aforementioned time course (across all subjects). At a given time $t_i$, the $j$th subject will have a measured $z_i$ value...i.e. $g_j(t_i)=z_i$. Using the same time window scheme as previously described (i.e. $t_{0+30k}$, $t_{1+30k}$, and $t_{2+30k}$ for $k \in \mathbb N \cup\{0\}$), I generate averages. For example, $Z_0^j=\frac{g_j(t_0)+g_j(t_1)+g_j(t_2)}{3}$.

Now, I create two final categories: $T_{pos}^j$ and $T_{neg}^j$. If $Y_k^j \in S_{pos}^j$, then $Z_k^j$ is assigned to $ T_{pos}^j$. If $Y_k^j \in S_{neg}^j$, then $Z_k^j$ is assigned to $ T_{neg}^j$.

---

What I would like to see is if there is a statistically significant difference between the following pools of data:

Data set 1: $D_1 = \{T_{pos}^1, T_{pos}^2, \cdots, T_{pos}^n\}$

Data set 2: $D_2 = \{T_{neg}^1, T_{neg}^2, \cdots, T_{neg}^n\}$

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Just to highlight some obstacles:

1. repeated measures without the same sample size;
2. post-hoc categorization
3. I'm sure quite a few other things...